# Open a same activity with videoView, with different video linked to each button

Tags: android, android-videoview

I've created an Activityc with a srollBar in which there is 16 blocs (includes tags), and on each bloc I got a button which goes to the same activity. In this one there is a videoView. I want all button to link to the same activity, but videoView reading a different video. Is it possible ? Help me please, I'm almost done with the app and i can't find a solution ahah !

[image: screenshot]

Here is my code for one bloc in .java :

```
frameLayoutPose = findViewById( R.id.updog_bloc );
customImageView = frameLayoutPose.findViewById( R.id.pose_img );
customImageView.setImageResource( R.drawable.urdhva );
poseSubtitle = frameLayoutPose.findViewById( R.id.pose_subtitle );
poseSubtitle.setText( "URDHVA MUKHA SVANASANA & BHUJAGASANA" );
poseTitle = frameLayoutPose.findViewById( R.id.pose_title );
poseTitle.setText( "Chien tête en haut & cobra" );
poseButton = frameLayoutPose.findViewById(R.id.pose_button);
poseButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.home_animation_android);
        Log.i( "OC_RSS", "You made it !" );
        Intent myIntent = new Intent( PosesActivity.this, VideoActivity.class );
        startActivity( myIntent );
    }
} );
```

THANKS

Answer (score 1):

In your activity set an OnClickListener for every button you have:
put video URL in your intent (like a package you send to someone with some extra gift card inside it)

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, DestinationActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("URL", "https://google.com");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

In your destination Activity get that URL from the intent that started the Activity (onCreate() is a good place):

```
String videoUrl = getIntent().getExtras().getString("URL");
if (videoUrl != null) {
    //Load video
}
```

**[Optional] A cleaner Approch is to override View.OnClickListener on your activity and:**

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String url = null
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_1:
                url = "https://google.com";
                break;
            case R.id.button_2:
                url = "https://medium.com";
                break;
        }

        if (url != null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, DestinationActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("URL", url);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Bro as i can see from your code you have hard-coded the video URI thats  why same video is showing on every button click if you want to show different video to different button clicks then you have to map the video URI  accordingly which is quiet simple.